# Add package (using TeXstudio)

Tags: packages, texstudio

I have package saved as .sty file and located in the same folder with the .tex. However it still displays as 'package not found'. Is there any way to add package?

Comment: What code do you use to add the package to your document?

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean I can ignore the 'package not found' message?

Comment: If your .tex fine compiles as you want, you can ignore the warning